# Inelegant/improper use of attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a class which I am using as a descriptor for an object.  In that descriptor, there are several `Type` references for classes that are to be instantiated for different operations involving that object.  I was thinking of pulling those references out and replacing them with attributes on the descriptor class.

From this:

```
class MyDescriptor : BaseDescriptor {
    public Type Op1Type { get; }
    public Type Op2Type { get; }
}
```

To this:

```
[Op1(typeof(foo))]
[Op2(typeof(bar))]
class MyDescriptor : BaseDescriptor {
}
```

I use attributes very rarely.  Would this be considered a bad use of them?

Comment: Have you thought about using Generics instead?

Comment: one problem is that you're baking the requirement to know the type at compile-time into the public interface if you use attributes. Using a virtual methods allows the usage of types not known at compile-time.

Comment: The derived classes may have different numbers of operations, so I wouldn't be able to have a static number of generic parameters.

Comment: CodeInChaos, you have a valid argument.  While there isn't anything in the current design that would require subclassing a descriptor, there's nothing preventing it, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good use of attributes, especially if you want to be able to instance the decorating classes through reflection prior to instancing the class they decorate. There are many benefits to using attributes, and this is just one.

Regardless of your intent, I don't see a problem with the implementation.

Comment: DI is still much better for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use **Dependency Injection** instead of baking the dependency into the Type itself at *compile time*.

I cannot see any benefit you can get from doing this over instantiating the dependencies by the class in its constructor or initialise.

Dependency Injection allow you to change such behaviour at runtime in addition to the ability to replace them with **dummy stubs/mocks**.

Comment: I'm pretty new to DI, having only been exposed to it at my most-recent job.  I not comfortable enough with it to try to implement it in this case, but I will use your suggestion as a launching point for some research on the subject.

Comment: This is pretty much you are looking for. Use Unity, Castle, StructureMap or any other and very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in the way you used attributes, but I also don't see any benefits you gained. Maybe if you share more information it would be easier to come up with a solution.

Comment: True, no tangible benefit from a coding standpoint.  The benefit I would hope to achieve is from a convention standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I use such way when want to specify what type of, for example, hash algorithm provider to use.

Child class has the attribute which will be read by parent class and it will create an instance of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are a fairly elegant way of expressing this in source code, but miserable runtime performance.

You'll want to build a cache at runtime to make lookups fast, perhaps using `Dictionary<Type, Type>`.